# LibGDX - How to draw a texture using camera and viewport

Tags: libgdx

I am new to LibGDX and I'm trying to understand how to use the Camera and Viewport to draw images in different parts of the screen. I'm trying a very simple example based on the base project, but I can't figure it out.

I have the following code:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    StretchViewport viewport;
    
    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(50, 50);
        viewport = new StretchViewport(camera.viewportWidth, camera.viewportHeight, camera);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        ScreenUtils.clear(1, 0, 0, 1);
        viewport.apply();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        img.dispose();
    }
}
```

If I understand this correctly, the camera should create a viewport of 50x50 world units. Then in the render() function, the viewport is set to current (with apply), the SpriteBatch is centered on the camera's viewport, and the texture should be drawn in the upper-right quarter of the screen.

Instead I get this:

[image: Red screen]

When running the simple base project (so without camera or viewport) the texture is drawn in the bottom-left corner.

What do I need to change in this code to get the image drawn in the upper-right corner?

Answer (score 1):

For the example you are working with you need to tell the `ViewPort` how big your screen is:

```
public void render () {
  ScreenUtils.clear(1, 0, 0, 1);
  // Add this line
  viewport.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
  viewport.apply();
```

otherwise it thinks the screen is zero pixels wide and zero pixels tall and nothing will be drawn at all.

Also, you are drawing the image at `(0, 0)` in view that is `(50, 50)` and the image is `(256, 256)`, so that is not going to be located in the upper right.

For sake of simplicity, if you are just starting out I would do this without any `Viewport`s and just use a camera, in the example below I set the world size to 500 instead of 50 to get the image to fit.

```
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;
    OrthographicCamera camera;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        
        // This creates a camera that views 500 units wide, and as many vertically as the aspect ratio of the window allows
        float aspectRatio = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        float worldWidth = 500;
        float worldHeight = worldWidth / aspectRatio;
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(worldWidth, worldHeight);
        camera.position.set(worldWidth / 2, worldHeight / 2, 1.0f); // Center the camera on the world so that lower-left of the screen is at (0, 0)
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        ScreenUtils.clear(1, 0, 0, 1);
        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        // Draw the image at the top-right corner by subtracting the width of the image from width of the camera viewport (and vice versa for the height).
        batch.draw(img, camera.viewportWidth - img.getWidth(), camera.viewportHeight - img.getHeight());
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        img.dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimenting, I understand better what I was meant to do.

Firstly, I simplified the code a bit by constructing the Viewport with an implicit camera, instead of explicitly creating a Camera (this has no real impact on the solution).

```
@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    viewport = new StretchViewport(50, 50);
}
```

The most important mistake was I forgot to add the resize() method:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height);
}
```

Next I added a height and width to the texture in the render() method:

```
@Override
public void render () {
    ScreenUtils.clear(1, 0, 0, 1);
    viewport.apply();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(viewport.getCamera().combined);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img, 0, 0, 25, 25);
    batch.end();
}
```

This scales the texture to 25x25 world units. Now it shows up nicely in the top-right corner.

The application essentially creates an infinite world measured in world units, with the camera opening a window from (-25,-25) to (25,25), centered on (0,0). Defining the resize() method is crucial. I had been thinking too much in terms of pixels still.